# How to advertise manufacturer specific data using bluetooth low energy protocol in Xamarin iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ads

I need to broadcast advertisement packets which contain certain manufacturer specific data using Bluetooth low energy protocol in Xamarin iOS. I am able to broadcast advertising packets, but when they are received they contain no manufacturer specific data. They do contain local name and data service UUID key which I'm setting. I should mention doing this in Xamarin Android is not a problem. Could you please tell me why manufacturer specific data is not being broadcast in Xamarin iOS? I am using the following code:

```
using CoreBluetooth;

namespace XamarinBt
{
    public class BluetoothOperations
    {
          CBPeripheralManager cbPeriphMang = new CBPeripheralManager();
          public void AdvertiseData()
          {
                var uui = new CBUUID[] { CBUUID.FromString("E20A39F4-73F5-4BC4-A12F-17D1AD07A961") };
                var nsArray = NSArray.FromObjects(uui);
                var nsObject = NSObject.FromObject(nsArray);

                var manufacturerDataBytes = new byte[6] { 5, 255, 76, 0, 25, 35 };

                var advertisementData = new NSDictionary(
                     CBAdvertisement.DataLocalNameKey, "id1",
                     CBAdvertisement.DataServiceUUIDsKey, nsObject,
                     CBAdvertisement.DataManufacturerDataKey, NSData.FromArray(manufacturerDataBytes));

                if(cbPeriphMang.Advertising) cbPeriphMang.StopAdvertising();

                cbPeriphMang.StartAdvertising(advertisementData);
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't specify manufacturer data in the advertisement.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheralmanager/1393252-startadvertising):

> **advertisementData**
>
> An optional dictionary containing the data you want to advertise. The possible keys of an advertisementData dictionary are detailed in
> `CBCentralManagerDelegate`
> . That said, only two of the keys are supported for peripheral manager objects:
> `CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey`
> and
> `CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey`.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks very much for pointing me to the API for startAdvertising method under CBPeripheralManager class. Since I'm using Xamarin I was looking at their API and didn't look far enough on Apple's website. It's a shame they are not allowing inclusion of CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey in advertising packets as I don't see any issues with that. It's quite a setback for me because I'm working on a project to control hardware devices with Bluetooth LE broadcast through not connectable advertising packets.

Comment: I can do the required quite easily on Android and Windows 10. I guess it means iOS is no longer an option except where data can be sent by forming a connection between an iPhone and the Bluetooth hub device.